# Changing from string.Format link to <a> link type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this string formatted link and i would like to use it in a  link for a button:

```
school => string.Format("<a class='add' href='{0}' title='Add {1} to {4}'><img class='pic2' alt='{2}' src='{3}'/></a>",
                                      Url.Action("AddSchoolToParty", "PartySchool",
                                      new { partyId = Model.PartyId, schoolId = school.SchoolId }),
                                      School.EntityName, string.Empty,
                                      Url.Content("~/Content/images/addImage.png"),
                                      School.EntityName)).Encode(false).Sortable(false);
```

and I wanted it to be something like this:

```
<a class="glossyBtn" href='<%:Url.Action("Create", "School")%>'>
                <img style="vertical-align: middle" alt="" src="<%:Url.Content("~/Content/blueprint/plugins/buttons/icons/add.png")%>" />
                <span style="vertical-align: middle">Add School</span> </a>
```

I would like the same information of the first code sample (`string.format`) into the second code sample format without the `string.format`

This is what i attempted:

```
<a class="glossyBtn" href='<%:Url.Action("AddSchoolToPartyPage", "PartySchool", new{partyId = Model.PartyId, schoolId = Model.SchoolId})%>'></a>
```

after running the page i get an error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "School_PartySchool_FK1". The conflict occurred in database "Kids", table "dbo.School", column 'SchoolId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: What actually is your problem?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I want to write the link that is in strin.format form into a regular link form without the string.format just using <a></a>

Comment: I didn't ask what you *want*. I asked what the *problem* with your current code is. If you don't have any code yet - produce it first and come back if you actually have a problem.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth my issue when i try to convert its format i am not sure how to substitute 'schoolId = school.SchoolId' because i dont have this school (parameter - ..Domain.Entities.School)

Comment: Where is the first code declared. Please show some context.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth all the code i am reffering to is above and i just added a third block showin an attempt of what i am looking for.